# Most efficient way to add items to an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

How can I write:

```
    buttons[0] = imageButton;
    buttons[1] = imageButton1;
```

etc more efficiently.  I have over 1000 buttons. I was hoping there is a better way to write this.

I tried the following and was forced to insert an & by XCode.  This code crashed my program:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++)
    {

        buttons[i] = &imageButton[i];
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: How is `buttons` declared ?

Comment: Yes is buttons an array? A vector? a std::array?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this with 1000 local variables called `imageButton1` to `imageButton1000`?

Comment: its some super natural data type, it holds reference as well as values.

Comment: `buttons` is an array `ImageButton* buttons[1100];`

Comment: Yes Dervall.  That is what I want.  Obviously I don't want to write out the code 1000 times

Comment: @DaveChambers: But you *already wrote* that code when you wrote out 1000 separate `imageButton` variables. You shouldn't have written those declarations to begin with; you should *replace* them with an array. If you have a thousand buttons, you make an array to store them, not an array to store pointers to a thousand variables.

Comment: @DaveChambers you need to have some better structure to your variables. Having a thousand differently named local variables would require 1000 calls to add, bar some trickery and unsafeness.

Comment: Thanks for the comments people.  I'll check it out.

Comment: OK, the penny dropped.  Thanks @NicolBolas.  Your comment opened my eyes

Answer (score 1):

if you have a vector of pointers and want to fill it quickly, you can just use this:

```
std::vector<t_button*> buttons(1000, 0); // << is that what you wanted?
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {
    buttons[i] = &imageButton[i];
}
```

of course, you'd need to ensure what you add to the vector outlives the vector itself because this is an array of pointers to buttons, not values.

if you have just a ton of free variables with unique addresses and unique names which have monotonically increasing suffixes, you'll likely be much happier in the long run if your store those values themselves in a vector:

```
std::vector<t_button> buttons(1000, 0); // << holds 1000 buttons by value
```

overall, the question is hard to answer -- it's worded like a performance question, but there are other semantic issues which need to be addressed first, and a lot of detail is missing.

Comment: But wouldn't this still require a thousand `push_back`s, one for each button?

Comment: `&imageButton[i]` is still going to crash for the guy, since it looks like he's applying an index to the address of a single pointer.

Comment: As I understand it, there is no array `imageButton`, but instead a thousand separate image button objects that follow the naming pattern `imageButtonX`. So indexing won't work on them.

Comment: @Kevin the question is lacking detail, and these details are coming in after the fact. expanded.

Comment: Hi guys.  I'll use an array I think.  I am very new to programming (it shows I'm sure).  I'll accept an answer once I've implemented the array.  Thanks

Comment: @DaveChambers alright - you're welcome. excuse me if i am stating the obvious in simple terms -- idk how new you are: think of `std::vector` as an array which may be resized dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using new C++ remember about emplace_back and move if possible. I guess button is a pointer? because you "&". Copying pointer and whole object are two different things. You should add a definition of button. Use .reserve to avoid unnecessary copying objects ( std::containers makes copies of objects by default).

Also remember that there in example ptr_vector in boost which will help you to stay clear.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vector to hold the address of the buttons

```
    std::vector< ImageButton* > Buttons;
    Buttons.push_back( &MyButton );

/* then */

   ImageButton* button = Buttons.at(i); // int i, is the index
   button->DoSomething();
```

for example you could

```
std::vector< ImageButton* > Buttons;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    ImageButton* button = new ImageButton;
    Buttons.push_back( button );
}

for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    ImageButton* button = Buttons.at(i);
    button->DoSomething();
}
```

If you're planning to use a fixed size for the container you might as well create a **Memory Pool**. Which will save you from heap fragmentation and nasty crashes.

Anyways I HIGHLY suggest using a **Memory Pool** as an alternative of using '**new**' alot.
1 **new** is better than 1000. It could even be **2000%** faster.

Comment: well its not particularly efficient performance wise due to the reallocations involved

Comment: @Doug T. I agree it isn't the most efficient way there is, but it gives you direct control over the elements and a very simple insertion mechanism which in my opinion worths waiting 100 extra milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using string connecting macro if you want to add imageButton1 to imageButton1000

```
#define imagebutton(X) imageButton##X
```

and can call this function from your loop. 
If you have imagebuttons as array you can do memcpy as well

```
memcpy(button, imagebutton, noOfButtons)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  In the end I used an array

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're declaring a thousand local variables named `imageButton1` through `imageButton1000` and now you want to put them in an array.

```
Button imageButton1("Save");
Button imageButton2("Load");
//...etc...
Button imageButton1000("Reticulate Splines");

//now that we've exhaustively created all the buttons, exhaustively put them into the array

buttons[1] = &imageButton1;
buttons[2] = &imageButton2;
//...etc...
buttons[1000] = &imageButton1000;
```

In my experience, putting a number in a variable name is a very strong signal that the data shouldn't be declared individually, and instead should be part of a collection of similar objects.

```
buttons[0] = new Button("Save");
buttons[1] = new Button("Load");
//...etc...
buttons[999] = new Button("Reticulate Splines");
```

You still have to spend a thousand lines filling the array, but this is unavoidable if you have a thousand completely unique objects. But at least this way is not *two* thousand lines long.

Comment: Actually all I needed in the end was an array.  Thanks